# Length of an infinite IntStream?

Tags: java, random, java-stream

I have created an randomIntStream by this:

```
 final static PrimitiveIterator.OfInt startValue = new Random().ints(0, 60).iterator();
```

The documentation says this stream is actually endless.

I want to understand what happens there in the backround.

`ints(0,60)` is generating an infinite stream of integers. If this is infinite, why  my machine is not leaking any memory?

I wonder, how many numbers are actually really generated and if this implemenentation can cause an error at the point where the stream still ends? Or will this stream constantly filled with new integers on the fly and it really never ends therefore?

And if I already ask this question, what is the **best practise right** now to generate random numbers nowadays?

Comment: Numbers (elements in the stream) are generated when they are needed and them immediately forgotten again (unless collected in a list, which would probably be a bad idea).

Comment: The challenge and beauty of infinity. You can't count it... Depending on how you use/store those numbers, you can manage to run out of memory. But I suppose you technically can't count an infinite set of numbers, because you'd have to wait for infinity... You'd have to stop somewhere

Comment: You don't need to create a new Random each time, you can use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` for example.

Comment: Using "memory leak" here is not correct. It's only a memory leak if memory is allocated while the programmer didn't intend to. You should say "why isn't an infinite amount of memory consumed".... but that... of course it's impossible for an infinite amount of memory to be consumed.

Comment: @ernest_k you can in fact count some (but not all) infinities. This concept is called countably infinite.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To be exact,

[`IntStream java.util.Random.ints(int randomNumberOrigin, int randomNumberBound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) returns:

> an **effectively unlimited** stream of pseudorandom int values, each conforming to the given origin (inclusive) and bound (exclusive).

This doesn't mean infinite. Looking at the Javadoc, you'll see an implementation note stating that it actually limits the returned `IntStream` to `Long.MAX_VALUE` elements:

> **Implementation Note:**
>
> This method is implemented to be equivalent to [ints(Long.MAX_VALUE, randomNumberOrigin, randomNumberBound)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-).

Of course `Long.MAX_VALUE` is a very large number, and therefore the returned `IntStream` can be seen as "effectively" without limit. For example, if you consume 1000000 `int`s of that stream every second, it will take you about 292471 years to run out of elements.

That said, as mentioned by the other answers, that `IntStream` only generates as many numbers as are required by its consumer (i.e. the terminal operation that consumes the `int`s).

Comment: As an additional consideration, when the source is `java.util.Random`, i.e. not a subclass with a different algorithm, the stream will “suddenly” stop after 2⁶³ elements, but it will also repeat after 2⁴⁸ elements, so if you didn’t get your task done after 2⁴⁸ elements, your problem is unlikely solvable with more than 2⁶³ elements either…

Answer (score 17):

The stream is infinite¹ so you can generate as many ints as you want without running out. It does not mean that it keeps generating them when you aren't asking for any.

How many numbers are actually generated depends on the code you write. Every time you retrieve a value from the iterator, a value is generated. None is generated in the background, so there's no "extra" memory being used.

¹ as far as your lifetime is concerned, see Eran's answer

Answer (score 5):

[Streams do not (in general<sup>1</sup>) store all of their elements in any kind of a data structure:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

> No storage. A stream is not a data structure that stores elements; instead, it conveys elements from a source such as a data structure, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel, through a pipeline of computational operations.

Instead, each stream element is computed one-by-one each time the stream advances. In your example, each random `int` would actually be computed when you invoke `startValue.nextInt()`.

So when we do e.g. `new Random().ints(0,60)`, the fact that the stream is effectively infinite isn't a problem, because no random `int`s are actually computed until we perform some action that traverses the stream. Once we do traverse the stream, `int`s are only computed when we request them.

Here's a small example using [`Stream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) (also an infinite stream) which shows this order of operations:

```
Stream.generate(() -> {
    System.out.println("generating...");
    return "hello!";
})
.limit(3)
.forEach(elem -> {
    System.out.println(elem);
});
```

The output of that code is:

```
generating...
hello!
generating...
hello!
generating...
hello!
```

Notice that our generator supplier is called once just before every call of our `forEach` consumer, and no more. If we didn't use `limit(3)`, the program could run forever, but it wouldn't run out of memory.

If we did `new Random().ints(0,60).forEach(...)`, it would work the same way. The stream would do `random.nextInt(60)` once before every call to the `forEach` consumer. The elements wouldn't be accumulated anywhere unless we used some action that required it, such as `distinct()` or a collector instead of `forEach`.

---

1. Some streams probably use a data structure behind the scenes for temporary storage. For example, it's common to use a stack during tree traversal algorithms. Also, some streams such as those created using a [`Stream.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html) will require a data structure to put their elements in.

Answer (score 4):

As said by @Kayaman in his answer. The stream is infinite in the way that numbers *can* be generated forever. The point lies in the word *can*. It does only generate numbers if you really request them. It will not just generate X amount of numbers and then stores them somewhere (unless you tell it to do so).

So if you want to generate *n* (where n is an integer) random numbers. You can just call the overload of `ints(0, 60)`, `ints(n, 0, 60)` on the stream returned by `Random#ints()`:

```
new Random().ints(n, 0, 60)
```

Above will still not generate *n* random numbers, because it is an `IntStream` which is lazily executed. So when not using a terminal operation (e.g. `collect()` or `forEach()`) nothing really happens.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a generator does not generate any numbers. In concept, this generator will continually generate new numbers; there is no point at which it would not return the next value when asked.